# How can I assure that the global scope JS scope (window) remains clean?

Tags: javascript, testing

Providing a third-party library is dangerous because the environments it's used in can vary quite a lot. Talking about JS run in a browser, accidentally overwriting a global (i.e. `window`) property, which is possibly used by another library, can break sites that rely heavily on scripts.

To avoid that, I'd like to automatically test if the global scope was modified in any unintended way, such as:

```
function foo() {
  myVar = 'this becomes global because of a missing var keyword';
}

window.jQuery = 'this is not jQuery at all, breaking everything that uses it';
```

(Am I missing another variant?)

### A typical example

My library packages a specific version of jQuery. Using `var myJQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);`, I can restore a pre-existing `$` and `jQuery`. If I forget to supply `true` as a parameter, only `$` is restored, and my version of jQuery remains in `window.jQuery`, possibly breaking other libraries that require a different version.

I'd like to have a test that can detect such a scenario automatically.

### What I tried so far

#### Static analysis with JSLint/JSHint

As far as I can tell, this only covers accidental globals due to the missing `var` keyword. "Intentional" `window` property assignments can not be detected, apparently.

There is JSHint's `global` configuration option, which allows me to specify whether a global property can be written to, but in that case, wouldn't I have to list all possible (or realistic) accidental globals I might encounter in the future?

Would be implementing a custom check looking for `window.something = ...` assignments a good idea?

#### Comparing `window` after a Jasmine spec with a snapshot of the `window` from before the spec

Since I have an extensive suite of Jasmine tests, making a snapshot of `window` before each spec, and comparing the current `window` with that snapshot after the spec was executed seemed like a good idea. The big advantage is that it covers many paths of execution. For a variety of reasons related to some legacy code, that didn't work out without major refactoring, which would take more time than I have.

#### Same as the above, but manually

That somewhat works, but it covers hardly any paths of execution, possibly leaving some cases of leaked globals undetected.

#### Taking care that the global scope is not modified during development

I could hardly find resources about automatically testing such a scenario, so it looks like most people are just careful to always use `var`, scope everything, and, if it's absolutely necessary, use as few globals as possible with very unique names. Maybe they also have the strategy to let if fail and roll back quickly once users start to complain.

This approach is not really satisfying as it lacks the rigor of automatic testing.

### tl;dr What I want to find out

- Is there an existing way to automatically test for global scope pollution?
- If not, what's the best way to do that in terms of thoroughness and required implementation effort?

Comment: The "forgotten `var`" case can be easily covered by using strict mode.

Comment: Using closure: `(function($) { /* Your code here. */ }(jQuery))`

Comment: You can't test for all those problems because for `function foo() {this.something = "bad value"; }` the `this` would be `window` depending on how `foo` is called. And this can only be detected at runtime or when you strictly define the usage and using a tool similar to the closure compiler of google, doing a closer analysis, but then you will loose much of the flexibility you have with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to leverage the coverage of our Jasmine tests after all. To do that (in Jasmine 1.x), you need to override `jasmine.Spec.prototype.addBeforesAndAftersToQueue` like:

```
var originalFunc = jasmine.Spec.prototype.addBeforesAndAftersToQueue;
jasmine.Spec.prototype.addBeforesAndAftersToQueue = function myReplacement() {
    this.queue.addBefore(new jasmine.Block(this.env, saveWindowSnapshot));

    // Call the original.
    originalFunc.apply(this, myReplacement.arguments);

    // Check for changes and expect to find no changes.
    this.queue.add(new jasmine.Block(this.env, function () {
        var changedProperties = compareSnapshotWithCurrent(...);
        expect(changedProperties.length).toEqual(0);
    }, this);
};
```

`compareSnapshotWithCurrent()` is best implemented recursively, so modifications of existing global objects' properties are noticed. Due to the size of the tree under `window`, a recursion depth limit of 4-5 is a good idea for a good balance of performance and thoroughness.

Since `window` contains circular references, it's also not a bad idea to track visited objects. If not recursion depth limit is set, this avoids infinite loops.

Some properties of `window` change naturally when scripts are run, such as  `window.location`. Depending on the execution environment, e.g. browser vs. PhantomJS, there may be additional or missing `window` properties. So for `compareSnapshotWithCurrent`, it makes sense to ignore whitelisted properties.

My implementation looks roughly like this:

```
// recursionLevel starts at 0 and is incremented on each descent to limit depth.
// propertyPrefix starts with 'window' and is a dot-separated "path" in the object
// tree under window.
// obj and snapshot are initially the window object and its snapshot, and on later
// recursions its children.
function compareSnapshotWithCurrent(recursionLevel, propertyPrefix, obj, snapshot) {
    var changedProperties = [];
    $.each(Object.keys(obj), function (index, propertyName) {
        var prefixedPropertyName = propertyPrefix + '.' + propertyName;
        var property = obj[propertyName];

        if (!isWhitelisted(prefixedPropertyName)) {
            // If snapshot doesn't have the property:
            changedProperties.push(prefixedPropertyName);
            // If the depth limit has not been exceeded yet, and the current
            // property is either function or object, and it has not been
            // visited before:
            // Track this property as visited.
            Array.push.apply(changedProperties, compareWindowObjSnapshotWithReality(
                recursionLevel + 1,
                prefixedPropertyName,
                property,
                snapshot[propertyName]);
            // Finally, if the property differs entirely from its snapshot
            // counterpart:
            changedProperties.push(prefixedPropertyName);
        }
    });

    return changedProperties;
}
```

Apologies for providing a pseudocode-y solution - because of IP reasons, I can only share the idea, not the source.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

> The `Object.freeze()` method freezes an object: that is, prevents new
>   properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from
>   being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their
>   enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed. In
>   essence the object is made effectively immutable.

So this line of code will prevent future modifications of `window`:

```js
Object.freeze(window);
```

Note this is very hardcore and will break lots of codes. After you use it, all codes which attempt to modify `window` will throw.

Comment: As you said, this is very hardcore and not an option for a third-party script, as it quite possibly breaks a lot of other scripts on the page. If there was a way to un-freeze `window`, it would be possible to construct something to protect the global scope while my code is running, though.